# How can I reliably and factually know which European country/regions/cities have much demand for a particular sector of employment?

Tags: job-search, europe

I am looking for employment in the region where I live, so far unsuccessfully. Some people advise me to try to find a job abroad.

However it is well known that the 2008 crisis is still going on and that many countries have lots of unemployment problems. It would be futile to apply in a region where the market for the sector of employment I'm in is already saturated.

Unemployment rate and the overall market's situation in a region do not have much meaning, as every sector is completely different: For example, it could be that in some region there is too much cooks in comparison with the market's demand because of a recent collapse in tourism, creating high numbers of unemployment, meanwhile there could be a cruel lack of engineers in that same region. It would then make me sense to apply for a position as an engineer, even though the unemployment in the region is high.

On the other hand, a country's economy could appear in a good state and have nice growth and unemployment numbers, but the market for engineers could be saturated, making any application from me futile.

I heard a lot of rumours people says, or articles that can be found on the internet, unfortunately this is not very factual and reliable sources.

My question is: **How can I reliably and factually know which European country/regions/cities have much demand for a particular sector of employment?**

I am really looking for *precise* categories, as for example in my region there is a huge demand for civil engineers and web developers, but not much for electrical engineering. Thus numbers shows high demand for engineers as a whole, but again, this does not mean much.

Comment: Not answering your question but : I am under the impression that south Germany has quite some opportunities in electronics (embedded Systems), and north-Germany in Electrics (Energy sector). A good job board website for germany is [link](de.indeed.com).

Comment: @Puzzled I was under that impression too. Before applying to south Germany though, it would be awesome to have factual proof of a demand for electronics/emedded systems engineers in the region. Also *south Germany* by itself is quite large, there is many cities and the situation might be greatly different among them.

Comment: You can also check out this recruiting firm : Optimus Search. I have been in contact with them in the past year and they are OK. They specialize in Engineering in Germany, Switzerland and UK. Submit your CV and they will very likely call you right away. They know the market well.
As for the cities, it is mainly around Munich, but also near Stuttgart, Frankfurt possibly.

Comment: One possible way is to look at wages. For example, look at these stats: http://www.bloomberg.com/visual-data/best-and-worst//highest-paid-software-engineers-countries If an occupation is commanding significantly higher pay than the median, there's a good chance it's in demand.

Comment: I think the strategy of guiding your job search by demand sounds perfectly reasonable on the surface (eg... you're likely to get more hits if demand for a particular skill is greater in one country than another). But there are so many other things to consider besides the raw probability of a job opening that fits you. It might be OK to rule out some regions because of awful economic conditions, but if city A has 30% more job openings than city B does that mean you should rule out city B? of course not. Much better strategy to focus on finding which companies you would be a perfect fit

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer:**
This answer aims at providing you means of getting an answer for yourself. I guess region and market specific statistics can be found, but it depends on the region and markets...

I would guess that what you really want about is getting a job. And that the present question only aims at optimizing your job search.

2 possible solutions (In your case, I'd go for the second one):

- Target a region and look for job ads in this region. You will figure out quickly whether the region has a lot of open positions in your field. That can take a bit of time though.
- Contact some recruiting firms that are specialized in Engineering. Then ask your questions about the markets. As usual, keep in mind that you are their product and that their answer might already have the goal of convincing you. Nevertheless, contacting these firms is not a big investment : if they have suitable positions, they will let you know and will get you into interviews.

So, my answers do not focus on getting "reliable" sources of statistics and information, but more on getting factual information. How to know whether there are open positions? Get interviews.

Comment: My very problem is that for the first solution, I need to pick the right region. Looking for jobs in all cities of EU in parallel is not quite realistic. As for your second solution, I'll have to try it.